# App rejected from Facebook App review because it didn't use Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As you may know, all apps must submit to app review before august 1st if they are using special Facebook API. Our application got rejected from Facebook App review because we don't use Facebook login to log in to our app :

> We couldn't find the Facebook Login button in your app.
>
> Please make
>   sure that the button is easy to find and consistent with the Facebook
>   brand guidelines. You can show us where to find the Facebook Login
>   button using your screencast and reviewer instructions. Go here to
>   learn more about making and submitting a successful screencast.

However, we don't want to use Facebook login. I don't specify in our submission that we want to use it. We use our own auth. I would like to know if all apps need to use Facebook login and if there is a possibility for us to get agreed without implementing facebook login. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: The whole point of the review is to acquire the permission to use their API. So if you're not using their API, then why are you even submitting your app for review in the first place?

Comment: We want the permission to use other API, and specifically manage_page and publish_page. This is why we do the app review. We don't want to use Facebook login if possible.

Comment: Without _any_ login, you won’t be able to acquire access tokens containing those permissions in the first place. If you just have a limited user base acquiring tokens outside of your app, for example by using Graph API Explorer, then describe that to them in your review instructions in very clear terms. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps describes what you should do when submitting this kind of app.

Comment: @user3819843 Did you succeed your app review? We are facing the same issue, the permissions that we need have been approved but the app verification failed with the exact same message "We couldn't find the Facebook Login button in your app." Also, there is no room to add comments for this specific element "App review". Thanks!

Comment: I've lodged two submissions for very similar apps, both requesting approval for manage_pages and publish_pages, and neither uses Facebook Login, as we only use the app in-house to post to our own pages, and generate the access tokens in the Graph API Explorer.  Both submissions referred extensively to the Server to Server guidelines (as in the comment above), and illustrated everything in detail in the screencast.  One was approved; the other only had manage_pages approved.  Can't figure that one out, so we've re-submitted.

Comment: @sideroxylon Our app have been approved. We check "Provide services to other businesses", we add a web plateform with the web api domain as url, then we created a test user, provided a demo website accessing our web api domain and check web plateform in the submission form. Hourray!